# Let $F(x,y,z)=\frac{-c r}{||r||^3}$ and $r = \langle x,y,z \rangle$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Compute $ \frac{ \partial F1}{\partial y}$ & $\frac{ \partial F2}{\partial x}$.

How do I do this if $F(x,y,z) = \frac{-cr}{||r||^3}$ is one function and not a vector of $<.F1.,.F2.>$?

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x,y,z) = \frac{-cr}{||r||^3} = \left \langle \frac{-cx}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}, \frac{-cy}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}, \frac{-cz}{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{3/2}}  \right \rangle $$

Calculate the partial derivatives of the components as asked.